# Bind rvalue reference to (auto generated) lvalue

Tags: c++, auto, rvalue, lvalue

My search found many posts on rvalue binding to lvalue but not anything similar. Sorry if it is a duplicate.

```
struct StrHolder {
    StrHolder(std::string&& s) : name(s) {}
    void Print() const { std::cout << "My name is " << name << std::endl; }
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    StrHolder s{"Tom"};  // (1) - OK, as expected
    s.Print();

    std::string n1 {"Angi"};
    StrHolder p{std::move(n1)};  // (2) - OK, also as expected
    p.Print();

    //StrHolder q{n1}; // (3) - NOT OK. Also expected. Cannot bind rvalue reference to lvalue
    //q.Print();

    auto name1 {"Bon"}; // name1 is an lvalue
    StrHolder z{name1}; // (4) - Why is this OK ?
    z.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

The variable 'name1' declared as auto, above is an lvalue. Therefore, initialization of 'z' should fail but it does not.

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but note that `name` should be initialised as `name(std::move(s))`, otherwise a copy will occur.

Comment: @Angew: True. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name1` is an lvalue... but it's not a `std::string`, it's a `char const*`. Constructing a `StrHolder` from it involves making a temporary `std::string` using its implicit constructor from `char const*`, then invoking `StrHolder::StrHolder()` with an rvalue reference to that temporary. `name1` gets left alone, and is never moved from.

Comment: (props to Agnew for noting in a since-deleted answer that `name1` has array type, not pointer type.)

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, that's why I deleted the answer. `auto` follows the same rules as template argument deduction, which *does* perform array-to-pointer conversions. ["Proof"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91a377ffb75d972a)

Comment: Hah. Then props to you *now* for correcting me. :-D

Comment: Thank you all for the swift answers. Example to generate the failure based on your inputs: auto name1{n1}; StrHolder z{name1};